# PHP - Adding similar keys when using (un)serialize

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I'm currently storing array values in a database using serialize, but the issue is when I go ahead and unserialize it removes similar keys.

So when I have a array serialized to something along these lines

```
a:2:{i:2;s:3:"400";i:2;s:3:"500";}
```

and I go ahead and unserialize it I get

```
Array ( [2] => 500 )
```

So it's just taking the second value if there's multiple values with the same key. Now is there any way I can make it so that when I unserialize it I get

```
Array ( [2] => 400+500 ) or Array ( [2] => 900 )
```

Essentially I want similar keys to be added instead of one just overlapping the other.

Comment: how did you manage to get a:2:{i:2;s:3:"400";i:2;s:3:"500";} ?

Comment: Figured it out, just had to write up a function that unserialized it and checked for any similar keys and added them in the final array.

Comment: Why not answer your question with the code you used to solve your problem? It might help someone else down the line.